# Fortify: fails to release a database resource

Tags: java, fortify

I am trying to see the vulnerability of my code with fortify. The report said that I have an issue which said "the function sometimes fails to release a database resource allocated by". Here is the code and in which line the issue pointed. I've tried to close the connection in the finally block but it not solve the issue. How to fix this?

```
private AnotherService anotherService;

private void create() {
    Connection conn = null;
    try {
        conn = getCon(); // With fortify, there's an issue which said "the function sometimes fails to release a database resource allocated by", and it refers to this line
        conn.setAutoCommit(false);
        anotherService.myFunction(conn);
        // the conn.commit() is inside anotherService, because I have to make one connection
        // rest of code

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace;
        if (null != conn) {
            conn.rollback();
        }
    } finally {
        if (null != conn) {
            conn.close();
        }
    }
}

private static Connection getCon() {
    Connection connection = null;
        try {
            Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection(
                    "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/dbname",
                    "username",
                    "password");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    return connection;
}
```

Addition:
If I use try-with-resource (like this `try (Connection conn = getCon()`), to automatically close things, how I could call conn.rollback() in the catch block if any exception occured? Since the conn variable declared inside the try-with-resources.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I solve my problem, the close method should call inside try-catch in the finally block, as mentioned in this [link](https://wiki.sei.cmu.edu/confluence/display/java/FIO04-J.+Release+resources+when+they+are+no+longer+needed).

In case the link broken, here is the code that I use to solve my problem:

```
Statement stmt = null;
ResultSet rs = null;
Connection conn = getConnection();
try {
  stmt = conn.createStatement();
  rs = stmt.executeQuery(sqlQuery);
  processResults(rs);
} catch (SQLException e) {
  // Forward to handler
} finally {
  try {
    if (rs != null) {rs.close();}
  } catch (SQLException e) {
    // Forward to handler
  } finally {
    try {
      if (stmt != null) {stmt.close();}
    } catch (SQLException e) {
      // Forward to handler
    } finally {
      try {
        if (conn != null) {conn.close();}
      } catch (SQLException e) {
        // Forward to handler
      }
    }
  }
}
```